# HTTP Error 404 when running the web app through Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, tomcat7, http-status-code-404

Even though the host website is running, am getting a 404 error while i am trying to run the web application i have developed through the eclipse.

Comment: Without more details it is impossible to say what might cause your problem.
Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry for that, after i have created a new dynamic web application , i have started my server and i have added the resource which i have configured with all the data i have given, but when am opening it on the browser, only the local host page is running properly, once when i add the path of my resource file, its showing me a 404 error.